# Generalized incomplete gamma function

Tags: r, distributions, gamma-distribution

As I know there is a built in function for incomplete gamma function, incgam(x, a), in R. May I know is there a built in function for the **generalized** incomplete gamma function? Or how can I modify the incomplete gamma built in function to get the generalized incomplete gamma function?

My generalized incomplete gamma function is $$gamma(a,x;b) = \int_x^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t-bt^{-1}} dt$$ and the incomplete gamma function is $$gamma(a,x) = \int_x^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t} dt$$

Comment: 1. Which generalized incomplete gamma do you mean? 2. To the extent that this is a "which function do I call?" question, this is unlikely to be [on topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: My generalized incomplete gamma function is $$gamma(a,x;b) = \int_x^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t-bt^{-1}} dt$$ and the incomplete gamma function is same as provided by Martijn below

Comment: Thanks; could you edit this crucial information into your question please

Answer (score 4):

#### For the case ${\Gamma(a,x,y) = \int_x^y t^{a-1}e^{-t} dt}$

You can compute the generalized incomplete gamma/beta/whatever function as the difference between two upper/lower incomplete functions. $$\begin{array}{rcl}\int_x^y f (t) dt &=& \int_0^y f (t) dt - \int_0^x f (t) dt \\&=& \int_x^1 f (t) dt - \int_y^1 f (t) dt   \\&=& \int_x^\infty f (t) dt - \int_y^\infty f (t) dt\end{array}$$

In your case with the `incgam` function from the `pracma` package, which is the *upper* incomplete gamma function $\int_x^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t} dt $ you have the third line and you can program this as

```r
gengam <- function(x, y, a) {
    pracma::incgam(x, a) - pracma::incgam(y, a)
}
```

#### For the case ${\Gamma(a,x,b) = \int_x^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t-bt^{-1}} dt}$

You can either use

1. a straigtforward integration (e.g. trapezium rule or other type of computation methods)
2. or you use a derived analytical form that might be computed faster.

For this second case there is some closed form solution (in terms of Bessel and error functions) given in *Chaudhry, M. Aslam, N. M. Temme, and E. J. M. Veling. "Asymptotics and closed form of a generalized incomplete gamma function." [Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics 67.2 (1996): 371-379](https://doi.org/10.1016/0377-0427(95)00018-6).*

In the case of half-integer values of $a$ ($\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{5}{2}, etc$) you can use:

$$\begin{multline} \Gamma(a,x;b) = b^{a/2} \lbrace K_a(2\sqrt{b}) + \pi(-1)^{a-1/2} I_a(2\sqrt{b}) \rbrace \, \text{erfc}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{b/x}) \\ + b^{a/2} K_a(2\sqrt{b}) \, \text{erfc}(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{b/x}) \\+ 2 e^{-x-b/x} \sum_{j=0}^{a-3/2} x^{j+1/2}b^{a/2-1/2j-1/4} \lbrace (-1)^{a+j+1/2} K_{j+1/2}(2\sqrt{b})I_a(2\sqrt{b})\\+I_{j+1/2}(2\sqrt{b})K_a(2\sqrt{b})\rbrace \end{multline}$$

<sup>(this is a slightly more simpler special case of an expression where $a$ is not restricted to half integer values, see this in [*Miller, Allen R., and Ira S. Moskowitz. "On certain generalized incomplete gamma functions." Journal of computational and applied mathematics 91.2 (1998): 179-190*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042798000314) )</sup>

Comparison of the two methods in R

```r
genincgam <- function(x, a, b) {
  if (mod(a+0.5,1) != 0) {
    stop("the variable 'a' must be a half integer")
  }

  # calculating pieces
      # storing K1 and I1 which are used several times
  K1 <- besselK(2*sqrt(b),a)  
  I1 <- besselI(2*sqrt(b),a)
      # summation term
  j <- c(0:(max(0,a-1.5)))  
  S <- sum( x^(j+0.5) * b^(a/2-0.5*j-0.25) * ( (-1)^(a+j+0.5) * besselK(2*sqrt(b),j+0.5)*I1 + besselI(2*sqrt(b),j+0.5)*K1))

  b^(a/2)*(K1 + pi *(-1)^(a-0.5)*I1) * erfc(sqrt(x)+sqrt(b/x)) +
  b^(a/2)*K1*erfc(sqrt(x)-sqrt(b/x)) +
  2*exp(-x-b/x) * S
}

f <- function(t, a, b) {
  t^(a-1)*exp(-t-b/t)
}

> # method 2
> genincgam(2, a = 0.5, b = 1)
[1] 0.05573681
> # method 1
> integrate(g <- function(t) f(t,a = 0.5, b = 1),  2, Inf, rel.tol=10^{-8})
0.05573681 with absolute error < 2.4e-09
> integrate(g <- function(t) f(t,a = 0.5, b = 1),  2, Inf, rel.tol=10^{-5})
0.05573681 with absolute error < 7.5e-07
> integrate(g <- function(t) f(t,a = 0.5, b = 1),  2, Inf, rel.tol=10^{-2})
0.05573628 with absolute error < 0.001
> #compare computation time
> system.time( replicate(10000,genincgam(2, a = 0.5, b = 1) ) )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.312   0.000   0.312 
> system.time( replicate(10000,integrate(g <- function(t) f(t,a = 0.5, b = 1),  2, Inf, rel.tol=10^{-8}) ) )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.788   0.000   0.787 
> system.time( replicate(10000,integrate(g <- function(t) f(t,a = 0.5, b = 1),  2, Inf, rel.tol=10^{-5}) ) )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.628   0.000   0.628 
> system.time( replicate(10000,integrate(g <- function(t) f(t,a = 0.5, b = 1),  2, Inf, rel.tol=10^{-2}) ) )
   user  system elapsed 
    0.3     0.0     0.3
```

It will depend somewhat on the values of the variables and the desired precision but in general the second case will be faster.

Comment: Hi Martijn, thank you for your reply. May I know how it going to put in R by using the incomplete gamma function, incgam(x, a)?

Comment: Actually I have a cdf which having the generalized incomplete gamma function such as in the form of (v/p, ax^p; ab). (Sorry, I don't know how to use the mathematics code.)

Comment: but my generalized incomplete gamma function is $$\int_x^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t-bt^{-1}} dt$$. Is it still using your suggest way to find it?

Comment: $$gamma(a,x;b) = \int_x^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t-bt^{-1}} dt$$

Comment: Ah I see. I should have anticipated that since generalisation is an ambiguous thing.

Comment: Any recommendation on how to put it in R?

Comment: Thank you Martijn on your advises. I'll try it out.

Comment: Thank you so much Martijn, really appreciate your work. 
May I know whether the workings you provided is applicable for $\Gamma({\lambda}/ \delta, \alpha x^{\delta}; \alpha \beta)\ $in which now the $a = {\lambda}/ \delta\ $, $x = \alpha x^{\delta} $ and $b = \alpha \beta$? And is it applicable for the lower generalized incomplete gamma function $\gamma({\lambda}/ \delta, \alpha x^{\delta}; \alpha \beta)\ $?

Comment: You can find the lower generalized incomplete gamma function with the upper generalized incomplete gamma function (the sum of the two together is a Bessel function), but with the method 1 that I describe you can compute it directly (just use different integration boundaries). Your parametization should work as well but note that the (faster) second method with the closed form expression only works for half integer values of $a$. If you need a more general case then you may be better of with method 1.

Comment: If you have troubles with this stuff then I advise to use method 1 (if it is fast enough for you). If you go for method 1 (direct computational integration) then you actually do not need the expression in the form of the generalized incomplete gamma function and you could just as well directly compute the integral of your probability density function, which might be a more intuitive procedure for you.